# How can I handle okhttp connection failed in kotlin android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, fatal-error

I'm using okHttp in Kotlin, but when the server is not running it throws an exception and crashes my app. I want

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
Process: com.mkapps.cvgen, PID: 24497
java.io.IOException: Unexpected code Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=INTERNAL SERVER ERROR, url=http://192.168.8.103:5000/name}
at com.mkapps.cvgen.fragments.CreateFragment.fetchGithubInfo(CreateFragment.kt:193)
at com.mkapps.cvgen.fragments.CreateFragment.access$fetchGithubInfo(CreateFragment.kt:26)
at com.mkapps.cvgen.fragments.CreateFragment$BackgroundFetcher.run(CreateFragment.kt:217)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)

```
val request = Request.Builder().url("http://192.168.8.103:5000/name").post(formBody).build()
    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()

    if (!response.isSuccessful){
                throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")
    }else if (response.isSuccessful){
        getUrlAsync(NRC)
    }

    return response.body!!.string()
```

Comment: There are many ways to handle it, for example, you can catch the exception and show a warning to the user that they don't have access to the server.

Comment: @user3738870 a sample code would really help

Comment: Sure, can you also show me how you're calling the method from which you return `response.body!!.string()`? Then I can show you exactly how to handle it there

Comment: https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#posting-a-multipart-request-kt-java
okay so I'm using the sample code in the above article

Comment: Okay, but how is your app using that code?

Comment: https://pl.kotl.in/HL-Q6AxFG
thats my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to notify the user that they don't have access to the server, you can do so in this way:

```kotlin
inner class BackgroundFetcher : Runnable {
    override fun run() {  // (3)
        try {
            val github_info = fetchGithubInfo()
            println(github_info)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            this@CreateFragment.requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@CreateFragment.requireActivity(),
                    "Make sure you have access to the server", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`runOnUiThread` is needed because `BackgroundFetcher` is run on a background thread, and showing a toast is only possible on the UI thread.